# 10-sided die with i faces

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

[image]

[image]

Could somebody please explain how this answer is derived? Why exactly these numbers to those events?

Comment: Change your username.

Comment: @b00nheT may i ask why?

Comment: It’s offensive and totally unnecessary. It’s not a joke.

Comment: @ThePoorJew Whether you are a jew or not, poor or not, is irrelevant and not of our business. The thing is though, on a math website (or physics, chemistry,etc alike) it is really about math and we try to keep religion, politics, ethnic background, financial status, gender and stuff like that, out of the spot light. Your username doesn't hurt me honestly, but most diplomatic approach is to use your own name, or some neutral name which only might be offensive to my cat. Hey, I don't even have a cat! That's my 2 cents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the question is means that the die has

- 1 face which is 1
- 2 faces which are 2
- 3 faces which are 3
- 4 faces which are 4

for a total of 10 faces. Hope this clears it up.

Comment: No, I still don't get it :( . I understand that it has 4 faces, and then it it displays i on it. i.e i=1 --> displays 1. i=2--> displays 2 and this way to 4..

Comment: um i literally said it has 10 faces and you said "i understand that it has 4 faces". that's not correct.

Comment: ohhh, so it would be like 1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4?. Okayyy I got it!

Comment: @ThePoorJew Yes, that's right.